# Can I make the Controller endpoint accept different json object (I have the matched class in java side)?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, generic-programming

I have different java class in Java side .

```
public class Prov{
  private String providerId = "";
  private String upin = "";
  ...
  //with getter and setter
}

public class Proc{
  private String procId = "";
  private String description = "";
  ...
  //with getter and setter
}

@Controller
public class Controller{

  @RequestMapping(value = "service/reports/prov", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String searchProv(@ResponseBody Prov prov){
  return "prov"
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "service/reports/proc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String searchProv(@ResponseBody Proc proc){
  return "proc"
  }
}
```

Now I have two endpoints defined in Controller , I wonder if it is possible to passing different json object to the same endpoint.

I tried using a inheritance class like C. Proc extends C and Prov extends C.
change the Controller to

```
@Controller
public class Controller{

  @RequestMapping(value = "service/reports", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String searchProv(@ResponseBody C c){
    if(c instanceof Prov){
      return "prov"
    }        
    if(c instanceof Proc){
      return "proc"
    }
  return "error"
  }
```

But It's not working. It gets ClassCastingException. I think that maybe caused by javascript don't have class inheritance.(Please tell me if I'm wrong .if you can explain the reason, that would be nice)
I think maybe generic class might help. But I'm not quite familiar with it.
Or any other way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get that exception? You can probably use Jackson polymorphic deserialization to solve this problem: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: Actually, I didn't get that exception here. I did when I was casting the Request object like       (Prov)c

Comment: Have you looked at Jackson polymorphic deserialization? You can make it work using properties in the class. It's probably the way to go here. I'll try to setup an example and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is make sure that your client sends inside the JSON extra data so that Jackson knows how to deserialize that object. For the examples below, I tested it with two JSONs:

```
{
  "type": "cat",
  "name": "Skippy"
}
```

and

```
{
  "type": "dog",
  "name": "Spike"
}
```

First you map yor classes using [Jackson Polymorfic Deserialization](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html). In my case I'm using an attribute called `type` to decide what class it will be deserialized to. The following is my base class `Animal`:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
public class Animal {

  private String name;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And my classes `Dog` and `Cat:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public void bark() {
    System.out.println("Au!");
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public void miau() {
    System.out.println("Miau!");
  }
}
```

In your controller you can do what you did normally:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "animal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String searchProv(@RequestBody Animal animal) {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
      ((Dog) animal).bark();
      return "dog";
    }
    if (animal instanceof Cat) {
      ((Cat) animal).miau();
      return "cat";
    }
    return "error";
  }
}
```